# Why are changes in git branch are getting copied to the main branch automatically?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am trying to use branches to work on different parts of my project. Let's say I am on the master branch and I have a file `test1` on it. Now, I create another branch and switch to it:

```
git branch first_branch
git checkout first_branch
```

Now I create another file, say `test2` and add some content to it. Now when I switch branch to `master`, I get:

```
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

But when I check the files now, I see the file `test2` with all the contents! How is that possible? I tried with multiple branches and everything simply gets copied across all the branches. This is not what I want since I want to keep my experimental work separate from an established work.

Comment: did you commit your changes to `first_branch` before switching back to `master`?

Comment: @GolfWolf: I didn't know that unless I do that all branches get modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended. `git checkout` takes un-added and un-committed changes across branches. This will happen if you do not call `git commit` before switching branches. So:

```
git checkout master ; git checkout -b first_branch
# modify test1
git add test1
git checkout master
# test1 still modified
git checkout -b second_branch
# test1 still modified
```

This is a feature: until you commit, all your changes are either only in the working directory, or, after you run `git add`, in the so-called "index". The index contains non-committed changes. Only after you run `git commit`, the current content of the index is converted into a proper commit object, after which the index itself will be empty again.